# Connecting to Postgres running in a docker image in Go using sqlx

Tags: postgresql, go

I have the following connection string

```
postgres://postgres:pw123@localhost:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable
```

This works fine when I try to connect to the database using docker compose:

```
docker-compose exec postgresql psql "postgres://postgres:pw123@localhost:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable"
```

I connect and can query the db.

When I try to use it with sqlx I get an error.

```
db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "postgres://postgres:pw123@localhost:5432/mydb?sslmode=disable")
```

I get this error:

> pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Does anyone know why I might be getting this from my sqlx when the same creds work fine for the docker compose?

**EDIT**: I tried changing to use the connection string that's listed as the preferred way of doing it but I have still the same issue:

```
args := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s sslmode=%s", "localhost", "5432", "mydb", "postgres", "pw123", "disable")

db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", args)
```

Comment: I think we need some additional details here. Is your Go application running in the same container as the postgresql server? Do the postgres logs show anything useful in response to the connection attempt?

Comment: As per the readme, it seems the connection string for `sqlx` using postgres is in the format: `user=foo dbname=bar sslmode=disable` ([readme](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#readme)). Same with the [DBR package](https://github.com/gocraft/dbr)

Comment: @larsks no, the Go app is running locally (for now). I dont see anything in the logs.

Comment: @ben10mexican I changed the connection string to that format but i get the same issue. Ill update the original post

Comment: @larsks In the terminal where i called docker compose i see logs. When i try to connect through my go program, no new logs are written. But when i try to log in using docker-compose exec postgresql psql with a wrong password i see new logs added. Not sure exactly what that means

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have two postgres instances running -- one in a container and one on your host. It would help if you could include your `docker-compose.yaml` file (or at least a [mcve]), as well as the output of `sudo ss -tlnp | grep 5432`.

Comment: Should have mentioned on I'm on windows. I might have one running locally though....I can check that when I get home again

Comment: @larsks i had a local instance of Postgres running. Turning that off solves my problem. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think this is from `pg_hba.conf` file:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/256534/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-pg-hba-conf-from-the-shell

There are lots of `[auth-options]` and `trust` is the one that's total open.

Sounds like your auth-option works for docker-compose but not from sqlx. Try changing them all to trust and restart postgres. If that works then go back and change them to what level of auth you want.